# A shorthand for multiple links?

Tags: shorthand

I have a fairly long list of quick links (approx. 20) that I'm going to embed on my main page. Instead of adding the full url of each link to the each anchor, is there a way to add maybe the end of each link.

For instance, if the link to the url is 
http://support.proboards.com/index.cgi?display&thread=423890
*as you can see, my forum is a proboards forum if that helps anything here.*

*the location of each url is local,*
Instead of adding the complete url, is there a way to use something like

`<a href = "&thread=423890">`
or maybe 
`<a href = "this.thread=423890">` ?

Answer (score 0):

Not in pure HTML, the best you'll get is `<a href="index.cgi?display&thread=423890">`, which is what you should already be using. Of course I'm assuming support.proboards.com is your site here.

You *could* use JavaScript and call a function like `openThread(423890)` if you *really* wanted, but a)I wonder what you really gain from it, b)this won't work for people with JavaScript turned off (a la NoScript), and c)I wonder if Google would properly see all the links.

Presumably, these pages are all being generated by server-side script anyway, so you should only really be coding `index.cgi?display&thread=` once anyway...

If you're hard-set on doing something shorter, I'd suggest using URL rewriting. You can have a URL like `.../display/thread/423890` and then use something shorter if you're already from a /display/thread/ page. But this requires the link to go to a page you have control over.

Comment: OK good enough, it at least shortens it up a little bit using the first example you explained. Thanks alot. That'll work!

Comment: @ShawnGameForreal Of course this assumes you are coming from that site...if it's a different domain, you're out of luck

Comment: Note, you may want to use ; rather than &, or to escape the & with &amp; if you care about syntax errors.

Comment: @barefootliam Why would you want to escape the `&`? It's a special character being used as a special character (GET separator)...